# 4-month-old cat licks a drop of honey, is there something to worry about?

Tags: cats, safety, diseases, eating

So this morning I was having breakfast with bread and honey, and apparently a drop of honey fell over the table. My little kitten saw the opportunity and jump over the table and "licked" the drop of honey.

I wonder if I should be worried about the botulism caused by *Clostridium botulinum* spores, given that the drop was quite small.

The vet isn't answering the phone and I would like to know if I should be doing something else!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
So the vet told me that if the kitten is healthy, and the quantity ingested was rather small, it shouldn't be a problem, and in his own words: "it's rather rare, and  there should be a concatenation of unlikely event for something to happen".